# How long can the comet C/2020 F3 (NEOWISE) will observed with the naked eye or small optics?

Tags: amateur-observing, comets

In the answer to the question
[Where should I be looking to see Neowise in southern Sweden?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/37083/where-should-i-be-looking-to-see-neowise-in-southern-sweden/37087#37087)
there is a picture with the comet positions till 30 July. In other sources I saw similar pictures also with 30 July as a last day. Will it be visible a couple days (or a week) after? Or it is totally unclear at now?

I live in a big city with a lot of ground light sources and high buildings and conditions for observations is not always acceptable. I have saw the comet about 19-20 July both with naked eye and with the 20x...50x monocular. And the next favourable period of observations begins about 27 July.

Thanks in advance.